# Can I replace SODIMM SDRAM with SODIMM DRAM in my laptop?

Tags: memory, asus-laptop, sdram

I have an Asus Vivobook X540UP laptop with 4gb SDRAM and I want to replace or expand it but I don't know if it is compatible or if I can change it into DDR3 or DDR4 RAM.

So, is it capable to be replaced into a DDR3 or DDR4?

Comment: Umm.. looking at the specs for that laptop, it requires DDR4 and supports up to 20/24GB depending in the original configuration. http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/vivobook-x540up

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official ASUS website](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-X540UP/specifications/), this system supports up to **16 GB** of **DDR4 SDRAM** memory. The standard one is 2133MHz but I couldn't find any information as to what the maximum supported frequency is.

According to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/vivobook-x540up), it supports up to 20 or 24 GB but I would trust the ASUS website more and not take the risk of buying an incompatible RAM stick.

Comment: Laptop has 1 onboard memory module, and one module for expansion.

Comment: Indeed it does. I misread the ASUS website page.

Answer (score 0):

I check official site:

https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-X540UP/

which mentioned that you cannot replace standard RAM but you can expand your ram but cannot not change DDR version because you must has same DDR version for motherboard and for RAM to work properly.
your laptop has DDR 4 version.